# Write to a VS Code window

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VS Code extension to output Hello World to the window when you click a button. It registers what language you are doing and bases the descision on that. I have written all of the logic apart from the actual writing to the screen but I cannot find out how to do that.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import "typescript";

let myStatusBar : vscode.StatusBarItem;

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext, { subscriptions }: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const codeBoilerplate = 'code-boilerplate.CodeBoilerPlate';
    subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand(codeBoilerplate, () => {
        const documentFileType = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId;
        const documentFileName = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName;

        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Generating your Code Boilerplate... ⌛")
        if (documentFileType === "javascript") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "python") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "typescript") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "csharp") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "c") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "cpp") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "java") {
            return null;
        }

        updateStatusBarItem();
    }));

    myStatusBar = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right, 100);
    myStatusBar.command = codeBoilerplate;
    subscriptions.push(myStatusBar);
}

function updateStatusBarItem(): void {
    myStatusBar.text = `$(new-file) Hello World!`;
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {
    console.log("code-boilerplate is deactivated!");
}
```

I tried using this method but it did not work...

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'console.log("Hello World!");');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the function you are using to insert the string into an editor is not going to even run in files with types you have listed (javascript etc.). Although, it worked perfectly in txt file for me. So I'd suggest you remove the following block of code or rewrite it so it would not return and stop the function execution.

```
if (documentFileType === "javascript") {
        return null;
    }
    else if (documentFileType === "python") {
        return null;
    }
    else if (documentFileType === "typescript") {
        return null;
    }
    else if (documentFileType === "csharp") {
        return null;
    }
    else if (documentFileType === "c") {
        return null;
    }
    else if (documentFileType === "cpp") {
        return null;
    }
    else if (documentFileType === "java") {
        return null;
    }
```